# ValidateAntiforgeryToken not working with Ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

Having this View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div id='calendar'></div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Services/Agenda.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

The following two lines of JS code are executed:

```
let form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
let token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();
```

Then this function is called:

```
function dbUpdate(data, startTime, title) {
    let evento = JSON.stringify({
        'Data': data,
        'StartTime': startTime,
        'Title': title,
        '__RequestVerificationToken': token
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Agenda/DbUpdate',
        data: evento,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("Response");
        },
        complete: function () {
            console.log("After");
        },
        failure: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("HTTP Status: " + jqXHR.status + "; Error Text: " + jqXHR.responseText); // Display error message
        }
    });
}
```

- Example of the Json generated:

```
  {
  "Data":"2020-0105T03:00:00.000Z",
  "StartTime":"8",
   "Title":"Sdf",
   "__RequestVerificationToken":"IMBfPM4YPyslt_89W6Kfu_Nmy6OW2-8I4n3fp42Figy__2gid3wY8gMC- 
   glB2o3Y6v6TCEG18nZXRPfLltU2RpOvoy-rMFIyo-uPA2XL4JcFF1aJfXix6RWkTI5l6Ewqhyu5jSQnszEOre2ZP-az3Q2"
  }
```

The controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
[AjaxAuthorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<JsonResult> DbUpdate(AgendaEvent compromisso)
{
    ...
    return Json("ok");
}
```

And the AgendaEvent class:

```
public DateTime Data { get; set; }
public string StartTime { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string __RequestVerificationToken { get; set; }
```

Just a note, if I make the class without the __RequestVerificationToken, thus being:

```
public DateTime Data { get; set; }
public string StartTime { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
```

I receive an error 404.

But the token, even though is present in the data passed is not validated.

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you receive the other data? The `JSON.stringify` converts your data object to a string, I think this is not needed, just pass the object to the AJAX method: `data: { .... }` instead of `data: "{ ... }"`

Comment: Also you don't need the `__RequestVerificationToken` property in your `AgendaEvent` class.

Comment: @lordvlad30 I already tried without it to the same result... Nothing changes...

Comment: You can also remove the `contentType` and `dataType` from the `ajax` parameters. jQuery automatically detects them (unless you need a non default one but JSON is default).

Comment: Regarding the __RequestVerificationToken property in the AgendaEvent class, it it isn't prersent I get an error 404...

Comment: Try using: `$.post("Agenda/DbUpdate", { your data object, not a string!  }).done(function(response) { ... }).fail(function(xhr) { ... })`. (this is almost the same as what you do but other syntax)

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the 404 error. What does it say because removing a property from your model should not give you an error.

Comment: Changing to $.post("Agenda/DbUpdate", { your data object, not a string! }).done(function(response) { ... }).fail(function(xhr) { ... }) continues the same...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206859/discussion-between-lordvlad30-and-sergio-di-fiore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by lordvlad30 the error was due the line:

```
let evento = JSON.stringify({
    'Data': data,
    'StartTime': startTime,
    'Title': title,
    '__RequestVerificationToken': token
});
```

Specifically, it's not supposed to have the JSON.stringify() statement. Thus, the correct is:

```
let evento = {
    'Data': data,
    'StartTime': startTime,
    'Title': title,
    '__RequestVerificationToken': token
};
```

And everything works!